# how to exclude a property from object while putting into hashmap in java

Tags: java, object, collections, hashmap, maps

Lets say, `Employee` class has three properties.

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    String team;

    public Employee(){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
    }
}
```

I want to remove `team` from the object before putting into `HashMap`.

```
Map<Integer, Employee> empMap = new HashMap<>();

Employee e1 = new Employee(100, "John", "Dev");
Employee e2 = new Employee(101, "Mary", "Dev");
Employee e3 = new Employee(103, "Andy", "QA");

empMap.put(e1.getId(), e1);
empMap.put(e2.getId(), e2);
empMap.put(e1.getId(), e3);
```

The values in `empMap` shouldn't have `team` property in it. Creating new objects would work but it is costly in real time. Is there a way to achieve this without creating new objects.

Comment: empMap.put(e1.getId(), e1.setTeam(null));

Comment: By "remove" what do you actually mean? Does it mean set property value to null?

Comment: @Rami In real time Objects will be coming from different sources with multiple properties and I want to retain only few properties as keeping all of them require more memory. And setting null would result in errors as those objects are being used in other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, as you have mentioned, is to create new objects without the team property. Another is to use a façade

```
public class MapEmpFacade extends Employee {
  public MapEmpFacade(Employee emp) {
    //define all methods to return the method results from emp, except for getTeam
  }
  public int getTeam() { return null; } //override getTeam
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may review your design to be sure you need the property to be there. 
You are holding `Employee` references in the `map`, the `team` property is there and probably is correctly representing an `Employee` ... you can just avoid using the `team` property ... or maybe you want to have a `Person` class.

If you are using those instances from some framework to do something (e.g.: serialization, persistence, etc) it should probably provide a way to ignore/skip a property in your object.